# Trying to add taxonomy to get_categories() but it's not working. How to fix this?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, categories

I have this template I purchased and I'm trying to customize.

I added a new taxonomy category called location and I'm trying to replace the default categories being loaded in the theme with my new taxonomy categories.

here's the current code and where it loads the categories:

```
 $cats_array = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
 $pages_array = get_pages('hide_empty=0');
 $site_pages = array();
 $site_cats = array();

 foreach ($pages_array as $pagg) {
$site_pages[$pagg->ID] = htmlspecialchars($pagg->post_title);
$pages_ids[] = $pagg->ID;
 }

 foreach ($cats_array as $categs) {
$site_cats[$categs->cat_ID] = $categs->cat_name;
$cats_ids[] = $categs->cat_ID;
 }


    array( "name" => "Featured Category",
           "id" => $shortname."_feat_cat",
           "type" => "select",
           "options" => $site_cats,
           "desc" => "description"),
```

Ideally, this change should work:

```
$cats_array = get_categories('hide_empty=0&taxonomy=location');
```

but it doesn't! I'm obviously missing something and don't know how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the register taxonomy part:

```
    // Register custom taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(  "location", 
                        array(  "woo_estate"    ), 
                        array ( "hierarchical"      => true, 
                                "label"             => "Locations", 
                                'labels'            => array(   'name'              => __('Locations'),
                                                                'singular_name'     => __('Location'),
                                                                'search_items'      => __('Search Real Estate'),
                                                                'popular_items'     => __('Popular Locations'),
                                                                'all_items'         => __('All Locations'),
                                                                'parent_item'       => __('Parent Location'),
                                                                'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Location:'),
                                                                'edit_item'         => __('Edit Location'),
                                                                'update_item'       => __('Update Location'),
                                                                'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Location'),
                                                                'new_item_name'     => __('New Location Name')  ), 
                                'public'            => true,
                                'show_ui'           => true,
                                    "rewrite"           => true )
                        );
```

The pages codes can also be found at:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Wkgg3

http://codepad.viper-7.com/n2hZRI

I wasn't able to fix the issue in the end, but instead of using the theme options file to dynamically select the category I want, I used an override code to directly (statically) select the category I wanted and it worked.

Comment: What does `$cats_array = get_categories('hide_empty=0&taxonomy=location');` return?

Comment: Nothing. the dropdown is blank when I apply that.

Comment: "*Nothing*". No. It returns *something*. What is that *something*? Is it an empty array? Is it `null`? What?

Comment: <select id="elegantestate_feat_cat" name="elegantestate_feat_cat">
<option></option>
</select>

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking what your `get_categories()` call returns; *not* what is ultimately output in your markup. Do a `var_dump( $cats_array )`.

Comment: This should be what you're looking for:

    object(WP_Error)#337 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Please include the callback, class, or whatever within which `register_taxonomy()` is called. The critical part is the **specific action** where that `register_taxonomy()` call is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix the issue in the end, but instead of using the theme options file to dynamically select the category I want, I used an override code to directly (statically) select the category I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
$terms = get_terms( 'location', 'hide_empty=0' );
if(is_wp_error($terms)){
    // error occurred
} else if (empty($terms )){
    // no terms were found
} else {
    // process terms
    foreach($terms as $term){
        // process this individual $term
    }
}
```

I'd advise you use the generic taxonomy & term functions everywhere, and avoid the special case category and tag functions where possible.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> This should be what you're looking for: `object(WP_Error)#337 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`

The error message reveals the problem: "**Invalid taxonomy**"

You're not passing a valid taxonomy to `get_categories()`.

Comment: but the same very exact call works on other pages.

    wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&show_count=0&selected=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&depth=1&show_option_all=All&name=locadu&id=locadu&taxonomy=location&exclude=1061');

works exactly like it should yet the same taxonomy doesn't work in get_categories().

Comment: What does `get_terms( 'location' )` return?

Comment: object(WP_Error)#517 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: And what does your `wp_dropdown_categories()` *on the same page* return?

Comment: Actually, I think you're a genius. Because although I didn't find how to fix it yet, I just found out the wp_dropdown_categories() code only works well in my theme's header file. in the same file that I'm editing right now, it returns with errors as well! 

So somehow the taxonomy that works when used anywhere in the theme's widget, index, header etc. doesn't work in the file I'm editing which is the theme's options file.

Comment: We'll figure it out. :) Next question: into *what action* is your `register_taxonomy()` function call hooked?

Comment: register_taxonomy( "location", 
       array( "woo_estate" ), 
       array ( "hierarchical"   => true, 
         "label"    => "Locations", 
         'labels'    => array( 'name'     => __('Locations'),
                 'singular_name'  => __('Location'),
                 'search_items'   => __('Search Real Estate'),
                 'popular_items'  => __('Popular Locations'),
                 'all_items'   => __('All Locations'),
                 'parent_item'   => __('Parent Location'),
                 'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Location:'),

Comment: 'edit_item'   => __('Edit Location'),
                 'update_item'  => __('Update Location'),
                 'add_new_item'   => __('Add New Location'),
                 'new_item_name'  => __('New Location Name') ), 
         'public'    => true,
         'show_ui'    => true,
         "rewrite"    => true )
       );

Comment: That's your `register_taxonomy()` call. It *should* be inside a callback function. Into what **action** is that callback hooked, via `add_action()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, I think I might have to send you the whole file somehow:

add_action("init", "WooEstateInit");
function WooEstateInit() { global $woowoo_estate; $woowoo_estate = new WooEstate(); }

Comment: That function is located after the register taxonomy part.

Comment: Just edit your original question to include all the relevant code for the taxonomy registration.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?vkaww4q442t4jue

The file where I can't view the taxonomy is options.php and the one registering is theme-custom-post-types.php

Comment: Please add the code to the original question, or at the very least, use Pastebin.

Comment: Pastebin is banned by my ISP. I added the code to the original question.

Here's the two files added to codepad:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Wkgg3

http://codepad.viper-7.com/n2hZRI